# How to insert Keras model into scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, keras, hyperparameters

I'm using a [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) custom pipeline (`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`) in conjunction with `RandomizedSearchCV` for hyper-parameter optimization. This works great.

Now I would like to insert a [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model as a first step into the pipeline. The parameters of the model should be optimized. The computed (fitted) [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model should then be used later on in the pipeline by other steps, so I think I have to store the model as a global variable so that the other pipeline steps can use it. Is this right?

I know that [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) offers some *wrappers* for the [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn)  API, but the problem is that these *wrappers* already do classification/regression, but I only want to compute the [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model and nothing else.

How can this be done?

For example, I have a method which returns the model:

```py
def create_model(file_path, argument2,...):
  ...
  return model
```

The method needs some fixed parameters like a `file_path` etc. but `X` and `y` are not needed (or can be ignored). The parameters of the model should be optimized (number of layers etc.).

Comment: can you explain what you mean by this "computed (fitted) Keras model should then be used later on in the pipeline by other steps"? If the Keras model is the last step, then how is it used later on by other steps?

Comment: ? perhaps [tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to **wrap your Keras model as a Scikit learn model** first and then proceed as usual.

Here's a quick example (I've omitted the imports for brevity)

> Here is a full blog post with this one and many other examples: [Scikit-learn Pipeline Examples](http://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipeline-examples)

```py
# create a function that returns a model, taking as parameters things you
# want to verify using cross-valdiation and model selection
def create_model(optimizer='adagrad',
                  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
                  dropout=0.2):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

# wrap the model using the function you created
clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model,verbose=0)

# just create the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('clf',clf)
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: in the keras model, there is no "input_dim" parameter. Is it a typing mistake?

Comment: This param_grid appears to be input to a grid or random search, but doesn't set_params only set the params without searching (hence there can't be a list for, eg, epochs)?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the go-to wrapper to use Keras models in scikit-learn seems to be [Scikeras](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras), since Keras/TensorFlow's own wrapper used in [Felipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47520976/1389680) is [gone](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/36137#issuecomment-726271760).

Answer (score -2):

This is a modification of the [RBM example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html#restricted-boltzmann-machine-features-for-digit-classification) in [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-rbm-logistic-classification-py), but the neural network implemented in [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) with [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) backend.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 27 17:11:21 2017

@author: ZED
"""

from __future__ import print_function

print(__doc__)

# Authors: Yann N. Dauphin, Vlad Niculae, Gabriel Synnaeve
# License: BSD

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.ndimage import convolve

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense,Activation
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils

from sklearn import  datasets, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


#%%
# Setting up

def nudge_dataset(X, Y):
    """
    This produces a dataset 5 times bigger than the original one,
    by moving the 8x8 images in X around by 1px to left, right, down, up
    """
    direction_vectors = [
        [[0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0]]]

    shift = lambda x, w: convolve(x.reshape((8, 8)), mode='constant',
                                  weights=w).ravel()
    X = np.concatenate([X] +
                        [np.apply_along_axis(shift, 1, X, vector)
                        for vector in direction_vectors])
    Y = np.concatenate([Y for _ in range(5)], axis=0)
    return X, Y

# Load Data
digits = datasets.load_digits()
X = np.asarray(digits.data, 'float32')
X, Y = nudge_dataset(X, digits.target)
X = (X - np.min(X, 0)) / (np.max(X, 0) + 0.0001)  # 0-1 scaling

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=0)

#%%
def create_model():
  
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=64))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    
    """
    #other layer
    model.add(Dense(500))
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    """
    
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

rbm = BernoulliRBM(random_state=0, verbose=True)

#This is the model you want. it is in sklearn format
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

classifier = Pipeline(steps=[('rbm', rbm), ('VNN', clf)])

#%%
# Training

# Hyper-parameters. These were set by cross-validation,
# using a GridSearchCV. Here we are not performing cross-validation to
# save time.
rbm.learning_rate = 0.06
rbm.n_iter = 20
# More components tend to give better prediction performance, but larger
# fitting time
rbm.n_components = 64

#adapt targets to hot matrix
yTrain = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train, 10)
# Training RBM-Logistic Pipeline
classifier.fit(X_train, yTrain)

#%%
# Evaluation

print()
print("NN using RBM features:\n%s\n" % (
    metrics.classification_report(
        Y_test,
        classifier.predict(X_test))))

#%%
# Plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(4.2, 4))
for i, comp in enumerate(rbm.components_):
    plt.subplot(10, 10, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(comp.reshape((8, 8)), cmap=plt.cm.gray_r,
                interpolation='nearest')
    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())
plt.suptitle('64 components extracted by RBM', fontsize=16)
plt.subplots_adjust(0.08, 0.02, 0.92, 0.85, 0.08, 0.23)

plt.show()
```