# How do I use Lime for an NLP CNN neural network multi class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, conv-neural-network, lime

I have a problem. I would like to output how the model has decided. I would like to use [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) for this. I have found the following [tutorial](https://marcotcr.github.io/lime/tutorials/Lime%20-%20multiclass.html). I have a free text field and would like to identify which case it is - this is to be solved with the help of a CNN neural network. I have several classes. However, I don't know how to use Lime, I tried it but got the following error.

How can I use Lime for a CNN with multiple classes?

```py
# Loading data
# data wragling
# ...

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
                                                    X,
                                                    y,
                                                    stratify=y, 
                                                    test_size=0.25)


## Tokenize the sentences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=num_unique_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_X))
train_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X)
test_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_X)

## Pad the sentences 
train_X = pad_sequences(train_X, maxlen=maxlen)
test_X = pad_sequences(test_X, maxlen=maxlen)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

#label encoding
le = LabelEncoder()
train_y = le.fit_transform(train_y.tolist())
test_y = le.transform(test_y.tolist())

#one hot encoding
train_y = to_categorical(train_y)
test_y = to_categorical(test_y)

%%time
EMBEDDING_FILE = r'./input/glove.42B.300d.txt'

def get_coefs(word,*arr): return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32')

embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE, encoding="utf-8"))

# since we only consider 'max_features' most frequent words, we update word index in tokenizer
tokenizer.word_index = {e:i for e,i in tokenizer.word_index.items() if i <= max_features}

#Creating a embedding matrix which is required as weights in the embedding layer on LSTM model
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 300))

for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector


class CNN_Text:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x =x
        self.y = y

    def forward(self):
            filter_sizes = [1,2,3,5]
            num_filters = 32
        
            inp = Input(shape=(maxlen, ))
            x = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], 300, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(inp)
            x = SpatialDropout1D(0.4)(x)
            x = Reshape((maxlen, embed_size, 1))(x)

            conv_0 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[0], embed_size), kernel_initializer='normal',
                                                                                            activation='elu')(x)
            conv_1 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[1], embed_size), kernel_initializer='normal',
                                                                                            activation='elu')(x)
            conv_2 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[2], embed_size), kernel_initializer='normal',
                                                                                            activation='elu')(x)
            conv_3 = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_size=(filter_sizes[3], embed_size), kernel_initializer='normal',
                                                                                            activation='elu')(x)

            maxpool_0 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(maxlen - filter_sizes[0] + 1, 1))(conv_0)
            maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(maxlen - filter_sizes[1] + 1, 1))(conv_1)
            maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(maxlen - filter_sizes[2] + 1, 1))(conv_2)
            maxpool_3 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(maxlen - filter_sizes[3] + 1, 1))(conv_3)

            z = Concatenate(axis=1)([maxpool_0
                                     , maxpool_1
                                     , maxpool_2
                                     , maxpool_3
                                     ]) 
            # z = Dropout(0.3)(z)  
            z = Flatten()(z)
            z = Dropout(0.3)(z)

            outp = Dense(53, activation="softmax")(z)

            model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=outp)
            model.summary()
            return model


p1 = CNN_Text(embedding_matrix.shape[0], maxlen)
model = p1.forward()

loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0009)
metrics = ["accuracy"]

model.compile(loss=loss ,optimizer = optim, metrics=metrics)

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(test_X, test_y))
```

What I tried

```py
from lime import lime_text
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from lime.lime_text import LimeTextExplainer

explainer = LimeTextExplainer(class_names=df_complete['forwarder_name'].unique())
c = make_pipeline(tokenizer, model)

[OUT]
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' '<keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer object at 0x00000163D3E86DC0>' (type <class 'keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer'>) doesn't
```

Example text: "I have been on this birth control for one cycle. After reading some of the reviews on this type and..."

What I want

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Why you get your error

You get this error because that `make_pipeline` can be applied to the `keras` model directly. You may refer to [How to insert Keras model into scikit-learn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42415076/9758790).

### How to fix it

Of course you can wrap your keras model into a "Scikit-Learn Pipeline", and make use of the build-in support of the scikit-learn classifiers in the Lime.

However, the Lime can be applied to `keras` model directly. In fact, as stated by the README.md in the Lime repo,

> "All we require is that the classifier implements a function that
> takes in raw text or a numpy array and outputs a probability for each
> class".

What you need is just a function with this kind of input and output, no matter the probability is computed by `keras`, `pytorch`, `sklearn` or anything.

These links may also help you to understand it:

- https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/issues/200
- https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/blob/master/doc/notebooks/Tutorial%20-%20Image%20Classification%20Keras.ipynb

### Code example

Take the `LimeTextExplainer` you are using as an example. What you need to do is something like:

```
explainer.explain_instance(text_instance, predict_use_keras, num_features=6, top_labels=2)
```

Here, `text_instance` is a `str` and `predict_use_keras` is a function, that "takes a list of d strings and outputs a (d, k) numpy array with prediction probabilities" as stated in [the document](https://lime-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html#lime.lime_text.LimeTextExplainer.explain_instance). Perhaps something like this:

```
def predict_use_keras(x):
    # do some preprocessing of input text
    # ...
    prob = model.predict(x)
    return prob
```